# Understanding DFA(Deterministic Finite Automaton)

Tags: automata

I have to provide a DFA for the following langage: $L=\{w|w$ is any string not in $a^*b^*\}$

For this problem, I think I have to use the complement; however, I don't clearly understand what $a^*b^*$ stands for. I think it's just all the strings in the form:

aaabbb
abbbb
aaaabbb
abab->wrong

by the way, I don't know if * includes the empty character.

Solution

Let's do the complement of the given language first

States={$q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$}
Alphabet={a,b}
Transition function:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& a & b \\ \hline
 q_0&q_1 &q_3 \\ \hline
 q_1&q_1&q_2\\ \hline
 q_2&q_4  &q_2 \\ \hline
q_3&q_4  &q_3 \\ \hline
q_4&q_4  &q_4 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Start state={$q_0$}
Accept states={$q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3$}

so the automata for the initial language is the same as the previous but it differs in the accept states

Accept states={$q_4$}

Comment: Yes, the $*$ includes the empty string. So your understanding of $a^{*}b^{*}$ seems to be correct -- it's all strings where first we have some (or none) of $a$'s followed by some (or none) of $b$'s.

Comment: I will provide the desired automata in a 5 tuple to see if it's right.

Comment: @zipirovich I posted the solution

Comment: It looks good and correct to me. Although I think that it can be simplified by combining states $q_3$ and $q_2$.